# How can I play as Judas?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

How do I unlock the playable character Judas? As the unlocking requirements are unknown. What exactly are the unlocking requirements?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can unlock **Judas** by first beating Mom, which will unlock two new dungeon levels called "The Womb". Then you have to beat The Womb, by killing the boss **Mom's heart**.

Comment: i beat mom and havent beat the womb but i will say some tips. 1:watch out for devil rooms,example,3heart items when you only have 3hearts isnt a good idea it will kill you
2:tri-shot is effective,if you have a choice,take it
3:the pact in devil rooms doesnt do anything! it turns your charecter black and takes you down 2hearts depending where you get it
4:the dead cat gives you 9 lives always go for that in devil rooms
5:if you get a judgement card and use it,or find a homeless person with a cent sign,give him money!one fatal mistake is NOT giving him money sometimes he gives powerups most time

Comment: @Dogarr: Allow me to point out some inaccuracies: 1. You don't have to be afraid of devil rooms, just think whether or not the items offered are worth the heart cost. 3. _The Pact_ increases your damage and range by 1 (so unless you have those maxed out, it does do something). 4. While The dead cat (_Guppy_) gives you 9 lives, it lowers you to 1 heart, and you start each new life with a single heart as well. That is not necessarily a good idea.

Comment: If you only have one heart left and buy Guppy, you will die, and use your first of your nine lives, always thought that was kind of funny

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an answer to this in the [Steam achievements of the game](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/BindingOfIsaac/achievements). First, lets look at a couple of achievemnts that seem to support this guess.

**Maggys Wig** 
*Collect 7+ container hearts in one play through*
This is the requirement to unlock Magdaiene. (As I recall it. Could have been less.)

**Cains Eyepatch**
*Collect 50+ pennies in one play through*
This is *almost* the requirement to unlock Cain. (The actual number is 55.)

Thus, I feel it's reasonable to assume that the requirement to unlock Judas is connected to the achievement

**Judas's Fez**
*Complete the full game*

What exactly this means, I do not know, as I haven't yet beaten Mom.

> And looking at the achievements it seems that just beating Mom isn't
>  enough.

Answer (score -2):

If this helps I unlocked him by killing "satin" to get to him you have to kill "moms heart" and a room will appear in the room with the large gold chest after betting her, keep in mind its realy hard. if possible use "Azazel" he is a bit overpowered.

The binding of issac: rebirth PS4

Comment: Binding of Isaac: Rebirth is a different game from the original Binding of Isaac. This question is about the original game.

Answer (score -3):

I believe killing blue baby or Satan (IE, beating the game) will unlock Judas as a playable character